# Compute the contour integral $\int_\gamma\frac{\sin z}{z^4}dz$

Tags: analysis, contour-integration

Im getting really confused looking at past exam style questions evaluating contour integrals... Can anyone help me in the right direction to solve these..

(i) $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \frac{\sin z}{z^4}dz$ where $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ and $0\leq t\leq2\pi $

(ii) $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(z-1)(z+3)}dz$ where $\gamma(t)=2e^{it}$  and $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ transversed in the anti-clockwise direction.

(iii) $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \frac{\cos^2 z}{z^2}dz$

(iv) $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(2z+1)(z+3)}dz$

Comment: Use Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Or the residue theorem.

Comment: Wenn you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\cos`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 1):

Hints (look for the residue(s) at the pole(s) within the integration contour!):

$$\color{red}{(1)}\;\;\;\frac{\sin z}{z^4}=\frac1{z^4}\left(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\ldots\right)=\frac1{z^3}-\frac1{6z}+\ldots$$

$$\color{red}{(2)}\;\;\;\frac1{(z+3)(z-1)}=\frac1{4(z-1)}\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}4}=\frac1{4(z-1)}\left(1-\frac{z-1}4+\frac{(z-1)^2}{16}+\ldots\right)=\ldots$$

$$\color{red}{(3)}\;\;\;\frac{\cos^2z}{z^2}=\frac1{z^2}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\ldots\right)^2=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(1-z^2+\ldots\right)=\ldots$$

$$\color{red}{(4)}\;\;\;\frac{1}{(2z+1)(z+3)}=\frac12\frac1{z+\frac12}\cdot\frac25\frac1{1+\frac25\left(z+\frac12\right)}=$$

$$=\frac1{5\left(z+\frac12\right)}+\left(1-\frac{2}{5}\left(z+\frac12\right)+\frac4{25}\left(z+\frac12\right)^2-\ldots\right)=\ldots$$

Comment: Yucks! The sine and cosine cables short-circuited in my mind. Thanks