# Calculate $\int_{γ}\frac{\sin z}{z^4}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Calculate $\int_{γ}\frac{\sin z}{z^4}dz$ where $γ$ is the unit circle.

I tried to consider $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z^3}$ so I can have $\int_{γ}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz$ and use Cauchy integral formula, but I realize I can't because $f(z)$ is not holomorphic on the disc centered at zero.

I am new to Cauchy formula trying to understand it (along with the course on complex analysis). I think a hint would be helpful because I am stuck.

Comment: Found with Approach0: [Compute the contour integral $\int_\gamma\frac{\sin z}{z^4}dz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378383/compute-the-contour-integral-int-gamma-frac-sin-zz4dz)

Comment: We have $$\int_\gamma\frac 1{z^4}\sin z\; dz=\int_\gamma\frac 1{z^4}\left(z-\frac 16z^3\right)\; dz + \int_\gamma\frac 1{z^4}\left(\sin z-\left(z-\frac 16z^3\right)\right)\; dz\ .$$ The last integral vanishes because we have a holomorphic function. Now compute by definition the integrals of $1/z^3$ and $1/z$ if using Cauchy is a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the residue theorem, $z=0$ is a singularity, then
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^4}dz=2\pi i Res(f;z=0)=2\pi i \left(\frac{-1}{6}\right)=-\frac{i\pi}{3}$$
By cauchy

$$\int_\gamma\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}=\frac{2\pi i}{n!}g^{n}(z_0)$$
where $g(z)=\sin(z)$ so $z=0$ $g(z)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$ then:

$\frac{d^3}{dz^3}g(z_0)=-1$ hence $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^4}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{3!}(-1)=-\frac{i\pi}{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

Notice you can write

$$\int_\gamma \frac{\sin z}{z^4}dz=\int_\gamma \frac{\sin z}{(z-0)^4}dz.$$

Thus by Cauchy integral formula, with $n=3$, one has

\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{\sin z}{(z-0)^4}dz&=\frac{2\pi i}{3!}f^{(3)}(\sin z)\bigg\vert_{z=0}&& \text{by Cauchy integral formula}\\
&=\frac{\pi i}{3}\bigg(-\cos z \bigg)\bigg\vert_{z=0} && \text{as $3$rd derivative of $\sin z$ is $-\cos z$}\\
&=-\frac{\pi i}{3}\cos (0)&& \text{evaluation at the point $z=0$}\\
&=-\frac{\pi i}{3} && \text{as $\cos(0)=1$}.
\end{align}

which is the desired result. Here, $f^{(3)}$ denotes the $3$rd derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$. Then,
$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin z}{z^4}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(e^{i\theta})ie^{-3i\theta}d\theta=-\frac i{3!}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=-\frac{\pi i}{3}.$$